# PHP different headers

Tags: php

Is it wrong to have more headers? I have a header now with a lot of links to external CSS. I am losing overview over all the links, because some of them is used on specific pages. Some pages use 4 CSS links, while another pages use 9 CSS links. So I often have a page where I am not using all the links I have in header.

Therefore I am thinking to make a

```
layout header/footer.php
core header/footer.php
module header/footer.php
```

etc.

Is that bad coding, or is it okay to have CSS links there is not used on all the pages in my header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to make a variable $css and you put all the css that you want to add in it. But a better way will be to use a variable witch will contains only variable css styles. Let's take this example, as we said the header.php will look like this:

```
<!-- this the header.php -->
<html>
<head>
[...]
<?php echo $additionalCss ?>
[...]
</head>
```

And let's say that we want to add bootstrap for a page called "login.php" but we don't need for all the pages of the siteweb. So my login.php will look like this:

```
<!-- login.php -->
$additionalCss = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />';
include("header.php");
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not quite sure of what you mean :-/

Comment: The variable "$css" might be a string like:  "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style1.css'>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='style2.css'>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='style3.css'>" ... and $additionalCss would be "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style4.css'>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='style5.css'>" ...

Not a bad idea, either.

Comment: Yes @Kkinsey you got it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I get it now. I will try to make that. Sounds like a good solution for me.

Comment: That's a pleasure ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's "bad coding"; it may indicate "bad design".  The main problem I'd think you'd encounter with your approach is the need to modify ***six*** files in the future (instead of just two) whenever the Marketing Department (or PHB) decides some new wording should go into the footer or header.

Generally speaking, browsers will cache all the CSS files for a site, so the fact that it's calling them shouldn't slow down your pages very much (I'm not client-side aware enough to know how much additional parsing time would happen in the browser, though).

Since they are PHP files, though, another thought:  you can definite a variable or CONSTANT that would tell the header and footer which CSS files they should include in the HTML output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kkinsey. Some very good points you have there. It is there first time I have such a big project that I am doing, so it could be defently what you are saying regarding bad design. At some point in my project, I wanted to many things at the same time. So I have used 1 week now, to restructure all my folders. So I will think of your points here in the future.